# change input type using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using this java script to change the input type for a field, it doesn't seem to work. please help

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" language="JavaScript">{literal}
    addLoadEvent(function () {
    document.getElementById(“form1").attributes["type"] = "text";
     }
    );
    {/literal}</script>
```

Comment: Note that changing the type of an input is not supported in all browsers (older IE versions).

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that you are using the correct ASCII characters in your code. It appears that:

```
getElementById(“form1")
```

should infact be:

```
getElementById("form1")
```

Note the different first quotation character.

Another note: I'm not sure what `{literal}` and `{/literal}` are, but if they are actually in your code, you should also try removing those if you continue to have problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 addLoadEvent(function () {
     document.getElementById("form1").setAttribute("type", "text");
 });
```

As Ryan pointed out, “form1" needs to be change to "form1". Also, attributes[] can cause some browser incompatibilities. [See here](http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/#attributes)

Comment: Why should the OP try that? What's wrong with their code?

Comment: “form1" to "form1". Also, attributes[] can cause some browser incompatibilities. [See here](http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/#attributes)

Comment: Best [edit] your answer and add this information. Also note that the problems with `attributes` don't apply in this case. The OP doesn't try to access the `style` attribute, nor is the attribute name uppercase.